How convert json file into dataframe with spark?
One of my task today is read a simpe json file convert into dataframe and do a loop over the dataframe and do some validations, etc...
This is part of my code:
bucket_name      = 'julio-s3'
json_source      = 'source/'
file_2           = "tmp.json"

json_s3_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{json_source}/{file_2}"
print(json_s3_path)

df = spark.read.json(json_s3_path)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

And here is the first error:
 AnalysisException:  Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV
 files are disallowed when the referenced columns only include the
 internal corrupt record column (named _corrupt_record by default). For
 example:
spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
 and
 spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
 Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the
 same query. For example, val df =
 spark.read.schema(schema).csv(file).cache() and then
 df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().

So, I test with the folloging :
multiline_df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(json_s3_path)
multiline_df.show(truncate=False)  
print(type(multiline_df))

and this is the result:
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|mySchema                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{{{NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, NVARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2}, Delta}, {{NVARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2}, Delta}, {{NVARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, NVARCHAR2}, Delta}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

And well my json file is something like this:
{
    "myschema": {
        "accounts": {
            "load_type": "daily",
            "fields": {
                "id": "nvarchar2",
                "isdeleted": "number",
                "master": "nvarchar2",
                "name": "nvarchar2"
            }
        },
        "customer": {
            "load_type": "daily",
            "fields": {
                "id": "nvarchar2",
                "accountid": "nvarchar2",
                "usergroupid": "nvarchar2"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "load_type": "daily",
            "fields": {
                "id": "nvarchar2",
                "isdeleted": "number",
                "name": "nvarchar2",
                "currency": "nvarchar2"
            }
        }
    }
}

I need to do a loop over the FIELDS object to find which of them are "NVARCHAR2" and print the key and the value, for example have something like this:
   TABLE       |COLUMN           |COLUMN_TYPE   |
   +-----------+-----------------+--------------+
   | accounts  |id               |NVARCHAR2     |
   | accounts  |master           |NVARCHAR2     |
   | accounts  |name             |NVARCHAR2     |
   | customer  |id               |NVARCHAR2     |
   | customer  |accountid        |NVARCHAR2     |
   | customer  |usergroupid      |NVARCHAR2     |
   | resources |id               |NVARCHAR2     |
   | resources |name             |NVARCHAR2     |
   | resources |currency         |NVARCHAR2     |
   +-----------+-----------------+--------------+

Can somebody help me to resolve this problem reading the json in a correct structure?
Regards

you can get the desired output using this code
final = []
table_level_df = df.select("myschema.*")
for i in table_level_df.columns:
    column_level_df = table_level_df.select(f"{i}.fields.*")
    row = [row.asDict() for row in column_level_df.collect()]
    for key in row[0]:
        final.append(
            {
                "TABLE":i,
                "COLUMN":key,
                "COLUMN_TYPE":row[0][key]
            }
        )

final_df = spark.createDataFrame(final)
final_df.where(col("COLUMN_TYPE") == "NVARCHAR2")

